# D3 fails to render after upgrade from v3 to v7

Tags: d3.js

Upgrading from d3 v3 to v7 and the chart no longer renders.

The old code in v3:

```
    d3.json("mydata", function(error, data) {
        var data = JSON.parse( '<?php echo json_encode($jsondata) ?>' );
```

If I create a file with the data from $jsondata (from the PHP code accessing the Database) and replace the lines above with

```
    d3.json("test.json").then(function(data) {
```

Then it works fine, can anyone help figure out theD3 v7 equivalent to allow me to use a PHP variable to generate the D3 chart?

Many Thanks

Richard

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of trial and error I found I could replace the lines with:

```
const data = JSON.parse( '<?php echo json_encode($jsondata) ?>' );
```